Как лучше хранить данные excel-файла?
Задача стоит следующая: пользователь выбирает заголовки столбцов, которые он хочет импортировать. Отмечу, что у нас разные файлы, с разными заголовками.
После этого на сай, скажем.. в формате таблицы отображаются эти заголовки с их данными.
Есть идея хранить это в json-формате, по типу ключ: значение, где ключ –> заголовок, а значение –> значение этого заголовка.
Как лучше действовать в этой ситуации, может быть лучше обойтись без json'a?

Сколько хранить планируете и на сколько много таких "разных" загрузок? Ну и формат этого мероприятия..  1 грузит все смотрят или сам загрузил, сам посмотрел и забыл?

Здравствуйте. По поводу хранения не могу вам ответить, таблицы могут быть и на 10.000 и на 40.000 данных. Сам вопрос в том, как лучше организовать миграции, просто в json-формате или как-то иначе можно сделать и обойтись без json

Мигрировать куда и на сколько? Вот есть пользователь, есть эксель - что дальше? Каков, скажем так, дальнейший бизнес процесс этого мероприяти?

Вопрос именно в хранении данных.

Жаль нет смайлика, бьющегося о стену... Ну хорошо, запихните данные в таблицу mysql(она у вас в тегах указана). БД как раз предназначена для хранения данных

Как и положено для таких задач - храним данные в базе данных. Делаем таблицу data_excel, с user_id колонкой и колонкой для хранения данных в json формате (если данные слишком разноплановые), либо в нормальной форме делаем column_name, column_value для названий и значений колонки. При необходимости, через N-кол-во времени, чистим через планировщик на кроне данные, которые пользователь выбрал но так и не импортировал.
